# Онлайн ящик в Godot 3

Tags: godot

Мне нужно сделать ящик RigidBody в Godot 3 3D, чтобы его координаты синхронизировались между клиентами и сервером. Я пытался отправлять координаты через rpc(), но это работает с багами, так как ящик RigidBody, и у него есть ускорение. Как еще можно сделать это?